# Css3 transition on scale only

Tags: css, scale, css-transitions

I am missing something obvious. But the transition on only one element isn't working here.

Here's my code.

```
#navigatore-servizi ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #008;
    display:block;
    width:240px;
    height:96px;
    background:#000;
    background-position: top center;
    line-height: 96px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
   -webkit-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-out; 
   -moz-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out; 
   -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-out; 
    transition: transform .3s ease-out; 
}

#navigatore-servizi ul li a:hover {
    background-position: bottom center;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
   -o-transform: scale(1.3);
   transform: scale(1.3);
    border-right: 10px solid #b00;
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You've got your

```
-webkit-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-out; 
-moz-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
```

switched. I have to assume that's the problem.