# Make Logo Shrink into Navbar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div whose height is bigger (120px vs the 75px navbar) than the navbar. Whenever someone starts scrolling I want the logo to transition to the same height as the navbar. I'm trying to toggle a CSS class with no luck, what am I overlooking? I'm using a Bootstrap navbar.

Here is the HTML for the fixed nav:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
        <div id="floating-logo">Logo</div>
      </a>
</div>
```

Here are the CSS classes:

```
#floating-logo {
    margin: -15px 50px 0 0;
    background-color: #FF9009;
    height: 120px;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 120px;
    width: 190px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 7px;
}

.tiny{
    height: 75px;
}
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function () {
    $('#floating-logo').toggleClass('tiny', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

I've even included a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkjmr6/2f4ofnsn/

Answer (score 1):

You need to shrink the img, not the div.
Try with

```
.tiny img {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, although what you are trying to achieve is not clear to me.
Your provided JSFiddle shows a logo that "bleeds" outside the navbar.
Is it supposed to be like this?

As stated above, target the image :

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function () {
    $('#floating-logo img').toggleClass('tiny', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/5s93bvay/).

Comment: Yes, the div containing the logo is intended to be taller than the rest of he nav.The nav is fixed, so as the page is scrolled the orange div (starts with height:120px) shrinks down to match the height of navbar (at 75px).

Answer (score 0):

If it helps you could also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533228/css3-transition-on-scale-only) to help you with the animation since you mentioned you'd like to transition

Answer (score -1):

```
var scrollTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();   
if (scrollTop > 0) {
    jQuery(".logo").css('width', '75px');
}
else {
    jQuery(".logo").css('width', '120px');
}

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var scrollTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();   
    if (scrollTop > 0) {
        jQuery(".logo").css('width', '75px');
    }
    else {
        jQuery(".logo").css('width', '120px');
    }
});

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();   
    if (scrollTop > 0) {
        jQuery(".logo").css('width', '75px');
    }
    else {
        jQuery(".logo").css('width', '120px');
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.